# WordPress: Execution of four conditions

Tags: wordpress, search, conditional-statements

Please, how can I do these four conditions, Knowing these orders pertaining to the search results

```
        <?php 
    while(have_posts())
    {
    the_post();
      if ($post->post_type == "book") {
         get_template_part( 'search', 'book' );
      }
      elseif ($post->post_type == "video")
      { get_template_part( 'search', 'video' ); }
      else { 
         get_template_part( 'search', 'normal' );

      } else { 
?>
          <p>Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.</p>
<?php
    }
}
    ?>
```

Gratefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your reply
The problem is why the state is placed before the following condition

```
 while(have_posts())
{
the_post();
```

Correct code:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php 
while(have_posts())
{
the_post();
  if ($post->post_type == "book") { get_template_part( 'search', 'book' ); }
  elseif ($post->post_type == "video") { get_template_part( 'search', 'video' ); }
  else { get_template_part( 'search', 'normal' ); }
} 
else : ?>
      <p>Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try    again with some different keywords.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you forget to end your `while` loop, use this code:

```
   <?php 
    while(have_posts())
    {
    the_post();
      if ($post->post_type == "book") {
         get_template_part( 'search', 'book' );
      }
      elseif ($post->post_type == "video")
      { get_template_part( 'search', 'video' ); }
      else { 
         get_template_part( 'search', 'normal' );

      } else { 
?>
          <p>Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try    again with some different keywords.</p>
    <?php
    }}
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but unfortunately the method did not work